# #DocuSignAPI How do I create an envelope that will match to a template

Tags: docusignapi

In the REST api guide, I see that I can send a document for signature, or send a template for signature, but I do not see in the reference on how to send a document that will be applied to a template (or how to specify what template I want to apply).

What method would I use to send the encoded pdf, and have that PDF match to a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify a template that you want to use in a REST call, you'll want to use **Composite Templates**, here is a good place to get you started.

*Keep in mind that StackOverflow is a place to request help with code and not a place to request help with designing workflows.*

---

### Composite Templates

> This structure can be added to create envelopes from a combination of
>   DocuSign templates and PDF forms. The basic envelope remains the same,
>   while the Composite Template adds new document and template overlays
>   into the envelope. There can be any number of Composite Template
>   structures in the envelope.

[DocuSign REST v2 Documentation. Page 110](https://08d1d92f490618f41c65-8fb00e97ac499a7066a18ce9c66b019b.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf#page=110)

Comment: @JoyFreytag good to hear! Please mark this answer as accepted if it solves your question, so that others can use it as a trusted answer.